# Extracting files from .phar archive

Tags: php, phar

There is something I entirely missed as for phar files. I am installing a project that requires phpunit, pdepend and other dependencies. I fetched them as .phar files. But, I am not able ot extract the files from them using command line tool (php command). I googled the problem, and I found nothing really answering the question. Could anyone help ?

Comment: Why would you want to extract them? You can use them directly as phar, see: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/924-Using-PHPUnit-from-a-PHP-Archive-PHAR.html

Comment: The link in the comment above goes to a 404 not found page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this library can do it: https://github.com/koto/phar-util

> phar-extract library.phar output-directory

Comment: Note that it seems not to work well with Phar archives [whose contents were gzipped](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pharfileinfo.compress.php). At least to me on Windows, but being a development setup, it has gzip, bz2, etc. so it should be able to extract them, but the results are mangled (and don't seem to be even valid as .gz files). The directory structure comes out correctly, though.

Answer (score 100):

Extending on @pozs’s answer, you can actually use [PharData->extractTo](https://php.net/phar.extractto) in a simple one-liner:

```
php -r '$phar = new Phar("phar-file.phar"); $phar->extractTo("./directory");'
```

Comment: did not work for me on windows PHP 5.6 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''$phar' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in Command line code on line 1`

Comment: @Oliboy50 Invert the `'` and `"` as `php -r "$phar = new Phar('phar-file.phar'); $phar->extractTo('./directory');"`. Probably a Windows-related quotes stuff.

Comment: Starting from PHP 5.4 you can even make it shorter: `(new Phar("phar-file.phar"))->extractTo("./directory");`

Comment: To fix the phar readonly error I did
`php -d phar.readonly=Off -r '(new Phar("phar-file.phar"))->extractTo("./directory");'`

Comment: Note that the PHAR file **must** have the `.phar` extension or you'll get an `UnexpectedValueException: Cannot create phar` error.

Answer (score 73):

Not sure if it's new, but under PHP 5.4.16 this works:

```
phar extract -f %some phar file%
```

The phar is extracted relative to your current working directory.

Comment: Works in Php 5.3.3 too

Comment: windows php 5.6 needs phar.phar extract -f %some phar file%

Comment: @Magicianeer that might just be how the phar command is installed in your environment, e.g even in Windows you should be able to rename `phar.phar` to `phar` and then the normal command would work.

Answer (score 15):

PhpStorm IDE can be used for viewing content of phar archives.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I'm using the latest current version (2016.3 I believe), and I cannot open a phar file.

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart PhpStorm to get the file indexed.

Comment: Tried that as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

http://unphar.com converts .phar files to .zip files easily.

Try it out.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just using it, you should include as `phar:///path/to/myphar.phar/file.php`.

But if you really want to unpack it, see the [PharData](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) class - no known (internal) extraction in command line, but you can write a script for that.

Answer (score 4):

PHP also has functions for extracting phar archives, but the files keep the current compression. To properly extract an archive it has to be converted into a uncompressed form first and then extracted:

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('Someclass.phar');
$phar2 = $phar->convertToExecutable (Phar::TAR,Phar::NONE); // Convert to an uncompressed tar archive
$phar2->extractTo('/some/path/'); // Extract all files
```

This will give you all the files uncompressed!

Comment: To extract readonly phar archives using cli use > 

php -dphar.readonly=0 extract.php 

the extract.php contains the code above .

Comment: `php -dphar.readonly=0 -r '(new Phar("archive.phar"))->convertToExecutable(Phar::TAR,Phar::NONE)->extractTo("./output");'`