# PHP Cli run file from my phar archive

Tags: php, phar

I have my project packed as phar.
I want to call some files from my phar using php cli.
like: `php /home/myproject.phar/work/worker.php`
For now I have next error: `Could not open input file` 
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: maybe useful? [Extracting files from .phar archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997385/extracting-files-from-phar-archive).  Maybe interesting? [Creating PHP Phar archives for command line programs](http://www.atkinson.kiwi/programming/creating-phar-cli-programs.html)